Generate onlyOperationTypes with typescript-mock-data
Working on a TypeScript project where using typescript-mock-data for generating mock data. In my codegen.ts file, I have set onlyOperationTypes: true in the configuration to generate mock data only for operation types.
However, when running the code generation, I am not getting the expected behavior. It seems like the onlyOperationTypes working well for graphql.ts file but removing all values from the mockers file. I have verified that other configuration options are working as expected.
I have checked the documentation for typescript-mock-data, but I couldn't find specific information about using onlyOperationTypes. Has anyone successfully used onlyOperationTypes with typescript-mock-data in a TypeScript project? If so, could you provide guidance on how to correctly configure it?
const config: CodegenConfig = {
overwrite: true,
hooks: {
    afterAllFileWrite: ['prettier --write'],
},
generates: {
    [TYPES_FILE]: {
        schema: graphQLEndpoint,
        documents: GRAPHQL_DOCUMENT_LOCATIONS,
        plugins: [
            {
                add: {
                    content: [autoGeneratedHeader],
                },
            },
            'typescript',
            'typescript-operations',
            'typescript-react-apollo',
        ],
        config: {
            avoidOptionals: {
                field: true,
                object: true,
                defaultValue: true,
            },
            namingConvention: {
                typeNames: 'keep',
                enumValues: 'change-case-all#upperCase',
            },
            exportFragmentSpreadSubTypes: true,
            preResolveTypes: true,
            // onlyOperationTypes: true,
        },
    },
    [MOCKERS_FILE]: {
        schema: graphQLEndpoint,
        documents: GRAPHQL_DOCUMENT_LOCATIONS,
        plugins: [
            {
                add: {
                    content: [autoGeneratedHeader],
                },
            },
            {
                'typescript-mock-data': {
                    typeNames: 'keep',
                    enumValues: 'change-case-all#upperCase',
                    terminateCircularRelationships: true,
                },
            },
        ],
        config: {
            withHooks: false,
            withComponent: false,
            scalars: {
                Time: 'string',
            },
            typesFile: 'src/services/graphql/generated/graphql.ts',
            avoidOptionals: {
                field: true,
                object: true,
                defaultValue: true,
            },
            namingConvention: {
                typeNames: 'keep',
                enumValues: 'change-case-all#upperCase',
            },
            defaultScalarType: 'unknown',
            preResolveTypes: true,
            // onlyOperationTypes: false,

        },
    },
},
};


I suggest you use typemocker.tech for generating online mock data based on typescript types.
